# What is $P (t_a < t_b < T)$ that $t_a$,$t_b$ are random variable and $T$ is fixed value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assuming $t_a$,$t_b$ are random variable that following the exponent distribution $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$ respectively and $T$ is fixed value,how to get $P (t_a < t_b < T)$ ?

I try to use two methods for getting $P (t_a < t_b < T)$, but the result is different.

who can help me?

The first method:

$\begin{array}{lll}
  P (t_a < t_b < T) & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (t_a < t_b < T, t_b = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (t_a < t_b < T|t_b = k) P (t_b = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (t_a < k) P (t_b = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T (1 - e^{- \lambda_a k}) \lambda_b e^{- \lambda_b k} d
  k\\
  & = & (1 - e^{- \lambda_a T}) - \lambda_b \left( 1 - \frac{e^{- (\lambda_a
  + \lambda_b) T}}{\lambda_a + \lambda_b} \right)
\end{array}$

The second method:

$\begin{array}{lll}
  P (t_a < t_b < T) & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (t_a < t_b < T, t_a = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (k < t_b < T|t_a = k) P (t_a = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T P (k < t_b < T) P (t_a = k) d k\\
  & = & \int_{k = 0}^T (e^{- \lambda_b k} - e^{- \lambda_b T}) \lambda_a e^{-
  \lambda_a k} d k\\
  & = & \lambda_a \left( 1 - \frac{e^{- (\lambda_a + \lambda_b) T}}{\lambda_a
  + \lambda_b} \right) - e^{- \lambda_b T} (1 - e^{- \lambda_a T})
\end{array}$

Comment: I think both methods are good. Both integrations look wrong to me. For the first one I get:$$\int_0^T\left(1-e^{-\lambda_a k}\right)\lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b k} dk = \left[-e^{-\lambda_b k} + \dfrac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_a+\lambda_b} e^{-(\lambda_a + \lambda_b) k}\right]_0^T \\ = - e^{-\lambda_b T} + \dfrac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_a+\lambda_b} e^{-(\lambda_a + \lambda_b) T} + \dfrac{\lambda_a}{\lambda_a+\lambda_b}$$ The second one gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We assume independence. We need to integrate the joint density over the triangle $0\lt x\lt y\lt T$. Expressing this as an iterated integral, we get
$$\int_{x=0}^T\lambda_a e^{-\lambda_ax}\left(\int_{y=x}^T \lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b y}\,dy\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Following you recommendation, my first method is wrong. why? my first method is also iterated integral.

Comment: I have only looked a little at the calculation, and at first look do not understand it. Maybe tomorrow I will.